# How to extract an excel file from RequestContext/HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

How can I extract the excel that is sent, from the HttpServletResponse?

I want to catch the excel file that is in the HttpServletResponse, modify it, then put it back into the response.

If I try this, the result is 0:

```
InputStream is = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getResponseDataStream();
System.out.println("Available = " + is.available());
```

If I try this, the result is null:

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
System.out.println(ctx.getResponseBody());
```

Where does the excel is transported? How can I catch the InputStream where the excel bytes are and use the following to get a workbook?

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

Comment: Generally the response is sent direct to the client, it isn't cached on the server

Comment: This is a proxy, I have to catch the response to make the modifies, then put it back in the response.